# Stop application restore on Android

Tags: android, process

I have an app that, upon startup, gets two session IDs from two different servers. The first activity is a "login" activity that performs this dual login, stores the session IDs and starts the main activity.

Sometimes my app is killed by Android due to low resources. When it is restored, Android restores the main activity right away, leaving me with potentially stale session IDs.

What I would like to happen is to tell Android *not* to restore the last running activity, but instead run the login activity again. There I will check the sessions IDs and log in again if necessary, and then move to whatever activity is required.

Is there a way to tell Android not to resume the app, but rather start it again?

Comment: Is that app or service?

Comment: so you can add finish() to onPause() or to onStop(). That way your app will be destroyed and will not resumed - it will re-created

Comment: Yes, although since I have multiple activities changed one after the other, this can get a little messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check on the session id in the main activity. If it is not what you expect, call the login activity again.
Something like:

```
    ...
    if (sessionId == null)
    {
        startLoginActivity();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: I don't like this solution, but I'm afraid this is the only one that makes sense - change the design of the app and have each activity starts the LoginActivity if the user is not logged in.